# Como pegar o id de um span clicado?

Tags: javascript, funções, get, id

tentei criar uma função que pega o id do `<span>` porém não consigo fazer ela retornar esse valor pra alguma variavel! consigo acessar só não consigo retornar o valor pra uma variavel

Answer (score 3):

Todos que responderam até agora estão esquecendo do óbvio, que **o elemento clicado fica disponível dentro do event handler, e de mais de uma maneira**. Dito isto, estou fechando a pergunta por falta de contexto.

```js
const spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');
const handler = function(e) {
    alert(e.target.id + ' / ' + this.id)
}
spans.forEach( span => span.addEventListener('click', handler, false) );
```

```html
<span id="primeiro_span">primeiro span</span><br>
<span id="segundo_span">segundo span</span><br>
```

Answer (score -3):

Neste exemplo, estou considerando que você tem só um span no seu html, ai esse spanId seria o id do span que você quer:

HTML

```html
<span id="12346">teste</span>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```js
var spanList = document.getElementsByTagName('span')
var spanId = spanList[0].id
console.log(spanId);
```

Mas se você tiver vários spans no seu html, e você não tem acesso ao id dele, tem que fazer um método que retorne esse id a partir do this, então ficaria :

HTML

```html
<span id="12346" onclick="spanHandler(this)">span</span>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```js
var spanId

function spanHandler(object) {
  span = object.id
  console.log(span);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```js
 var span = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
    var size = span.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      span[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          if (this === span[i]) {
            Var = span[i].id;
            alert(Var);
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span id="999">Hello World</span>
    <span id="1">África do Sul</span>
    <span id="2">Egito</span>
    <span id="3">Mali</span>
    <span id="4">Serra</span>
    <span id="5">Angola</span>
    <span id="6">Eritreia</span>
    <span id="7">Marrocos</span>
    <span id="8">Seicheles</span>
  </body>
  <script>
    var span = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
    var size = span.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      span[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          if (this === span[i]) {
            Var = span[i].id;
            alert(Var);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

var span = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
var size = span.length;
for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
span[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
if (this === span[i]) {
Var = span[i].id;
alert(Var);
}
}
});
}

Answer (score -4):

Para armazenar o ID do elemento que deseja em uma variável ao clicar nele, pode-se fazer assim:

```
// Pegar todos os spans
const spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

// Essa variável é para armazenar o ID do último elemento que foi clicado.
let lastId; 

/*

Percorre todos os spans,
adiciona um evento de clique a cada um deles
e quando um dos elementos forem clicados
o id do elemento clicado
será atribuído para a variável `lastId`

*/

for (const span of spans) {
  span.addEventListener('click', () => {
    lastId = span.id;
  });
}
```

**VEJA UM EXEMPLO A SEGUIR:**

```js
// Pegar todos os spans
const spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

// Essa variável é para armazenar o ID do último elemento que foi clicado.
let lastId;

/*

Percorre todos os spans,
adiciona um evento de clique a cada um deles
e quando um dos elementos forem clicados
o id do elemento clicado
será atribuído para a variável `lastId`

*/

for (const span of spans) {
  span.addEventListener('click', () => {
    lastId = span.id;
  });
}

/*

Função de exemplo
Verifica se não é `undefined`
Se não for, ele alerta o ID
Que está na variável `lastId`

*/

function teste() {
    if (lastId !== undefined) {
        alert(lastId);
    }
}
```

```html
<span id="id1stack">SPAN 1- CLIQUE AQUI PARA SALVAR MEU ID</span>
<br /><br />
<span id="id2stack">SPAN 2- CLIQUE AQUI PARA SALVAR MEU ID</span>
    
<br /><br />
    
<button onclick="teste()">CLIQUE PARA VER O ID DO SPAN CLICADO</button>
```